# Python capture group and quote it with regex

Tags: python, regex, capture

I'm trying to use a regex to capture data from a file and quote it. I want to capture anything between "Postal Code": and a comma. When I replace that value, it shows like this "whateverdata (with no quote on the end.) Why is that?

Data will look something like this: `"State":"NC","Postal Code":27605,"Description":null,`

My code:

```
pattern = r'"Postal Code":(.+),'
replacement = r'"\1"'
jsonObj = re.sub(pattern, replacement, jsonObj)
```

Since this is json, is there a better way to go about this? Seems like it would be a common problem

Comment: Comments like this, should be included in the question itself.

Comment: You need to use a non-**greedy** quantifier instead. `(.+?)`

Comment: You might try json.loads()

Comment: json.loads() fails if there is a number with a leading 0, which there can be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either use a *non-greedy match* here (as @hwnd suggested in comments):

```
r'"Postal Code":(.+?),'
```

Or, since you know that this is a postal-code, match *one or more digits*:

```
r'"Postal Code":(\d+),'
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'"Postal Code":(\d+),')
>>> source = '"State":"NC","Postal Code":27605,"Description":null,'
>>> pattern.search(source).group(1)
'27605'
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `+` [**greedy**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html) operator. It will match as much as it can and still allow the remainder of the regular expression to match until it reaches the last comma in the line.

Use `+?` for a non-greedy match meaning "one or more — preferably as few as possible".

```
pattern = r'"Postal Code":(.+?),'
```